# Ocean Frequencies

Tags: water, resonance

I'm a musician studying at uni. For an assessment I'm taking an idea for instrumental tuning which relies on a combination of **Pythagorean tuning** and **Schumann resonances**. 
Whilst Schumann resonance I believe is for the Earth as a whole, is there a way to identify the resonance of bodies of water? Or an average resonance for water as a whole, not necessarily a single water molecule.

Answer (score 2):

While [Pythagorean tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_tuning) is a system of musical tuning, [Schumann resonances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schumann_resonances) are a set of spectrum peaks in the extremely low frequency (ELF) portion of the Earth's electromagnetic field spectrum, so perhaps you could elaborate on how you might use a combination of Pythagorean tuning and Schumann resonances for instrumental tuning?

However, for physical waves related to water, a ***[seiche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiche)*** is a standing wave in an enclosed or partially enclosed body of water.

> Seiches and seiche-related phenomena have been observed on lakes, reservoirs, swimming pools, bays, harbours and seas. The key requirement for formation of a seiche is that the body of water be at least partially bounded, allowing the formation of the standing wave.

Seiches have been known and observed for some time. The longest natural period of a seiche is the period associated with the fundamental resonance for the body of water. For a surface seiche in an enclosed rectangular body of water this can be estimated using Merian's formula:

$$T = \frac{2L}{\sqrt{gh}}$$

where $T$ is the longest natural period, $L$ is the length, $h$ the average depth of the body of water, and $g$ the acceleration of gravity.

Higher order harmonics are also observed, so perhaps this is useful to you?

Comment: Thanks Mick. The idea of Pythagorean tuning and Schumann resonance is that instead of tuning to regular notes, frequency are changed to match the ratio of Pythagorean tuning (3:2), with the bass starting at what I believe is the average Schumann resonancy, 7.82 Hz. This piece is inspired by the lake Tonle Sap in Cambodia, so with this information I was hoping to try and find some sort of average resonancy to use to bass Pythagorean tuning on.